# Is there any way to show two emulator for Sub Display(Presentation Class)?

Tags: android, multiple-monitors, android-presentation

I am working with [Presentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation) Class to show different screen to the customers, but interact together.

But I have no idea how to test this out because my devices and emulators only show one screen.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hardware, you may be able to connect an external display. For example, many modern Samsung devices support USB-C to HDMI adapters.

For the emulator and hardware that does not support external displays, you can simulate an external display. In Developer Options, scroll down to "[Simulate secondary displays](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator)", and from there choose a resolution for the secondary display. This will appear as a floating layer over the main device UI, and it will work with `Presentation`.

Comment: I think the `Simulate secondary displays` is supported from API 28(I guess for Foldable phones). But my device will be API 24. I need to connect two tablets. And also need to display them in landscape mode.

Comment: @c-an: "I think the Simulate secondary displays is supported from API 28" -- it has been supported on hardware since Android 4.2. I forget when they enabled it on emulators, but I am fairly certain it was before Android 9. "I need to connect two tablets" -- you will need to talk to your device manufacturer to see if its tablet also supports being a external display. Alternatively, you will need to seek solutions that do not involve `Presentation`, which is for working with external displays.

Comment: I figured it out. But Is 'Presentation' touchable? I think it is possible because it inherits dialog class.

Comment: @c-an: "But Is 'Presentation' touchable?" -- not normally, because normally it is used with a regular monitor/TV/projector. TVs, for example, are not touchscreens, except in the presence of small children. :-) I have never tried hooking up an Android device to a touchscreen monitor to see if `Presentation` supports touch input.